# Select only text and images in css

Tags: html, css, image, text

I would like to put an animation to the text and the images of my web page but without selecting the other elements.
This is the code of my animation :

```
@keyframes load {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translate(-125px);
    }
    10% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translate(-125px);
    }
    20% {
        opacity: 0.2;
    }
    40% {
        opacity: 0.4;
    }
    60% {
        opacity: 0.6;
    }
    80% {
        opacity: 0.8;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translate(0px);
    }
}
```

And so my goal is to make an animation that only takes into account the text and the images.

I tried to find a selector that could meet my needs but without result and I tried to put this animation in the body tag but the problem is that it also selects other elements such as divs, but I only tries to target images and text.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what is meant by 'text' in this context. Text is usually held in elements (such as divs) so why wouln't you want to change the opacity of a div holding text. Perhaps I'd understand a bit more if you could give some examples of things that should NOT have their opacity changed on load? Would it be things like say the background color of a div?

Comment: Yes that's exactly it ! I want the other properties such as the background or the borders etc... to remain intact and that the animation goes only to the text or if you prefer its content.

Comment: You need to give some example HTML, and note that text is only selectable by CSS if it’s in an element, so what happens if that element also has say a background?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply animation on selected text and image then You can use class or id selector for that.

```css
@keyframes load {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translate(-125px);
    }
    10% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translate(-125px);
    }
    20% {
        opacity: 0.2;
    }
    40% {
        opacity: 0.4;
    }
    60% {
        opacity: 0.6;
    }
    80% {
        opacity: 0.8;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translate(0px);
    }
}

.demo{
animation-name: load;
animation-duration: 2s;
}
```

```html
<span class="demo">Hello</span>
<span class="demo">World</span>
```

Comment: Yes but then the background or other properties would also be affected but I want the animation to really only focus on the text.

Comment: If i am understanding right then what you want is that suppose there is a div with background color black whichi contains image inside it now you want to animate the opacity of the image but you don't want to apply that animation of opacity on background color black right ? if yes then also you will use class and id <div class='demo'><img src='img.png' id='demoImage'></div> now css part #demoImage{animation-name: load;} other thing you can do .demo img{animation-name: load;}

Comment: yes but if i select the whole page how can i do?